# Convert date from '300520231644' to '30/05/2023 16:44'

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I convert from the string `'300520231644'` to a date 30/05/2023 16:44?

I tried to use this code below:

```sql
SELECT to_date('3005231429', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss') FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `TO_TIMESTAMP` to convert string into datetime, then `TO_CHAR` to convert datetime into the format needed :

```
SELECT to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP('3005231429', 'ddmmyyHH24mi'), 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi') FROM dual;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2PcCd6wP)

Comment: You do not heed `TO_TIMESTAMP`, `TO_DATE` is sufficient as dates in Oracle always have a time component.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value as a `DATE` then you need to use either `YYYY` for a four-digit year and `HH24` for a hours in a 24-hour clock:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE('3005231429', 'DDMMYYYYHH24MI') FROM DUAL;
```

The client application you are using will then display the date using whatever default date format it is set to and may choose not to show the time component of the date (however, that does not mean that the time component is not there, it is only not being displayed).

For SQL*Plus and SQL Developer (and maybe others) use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as default format for displaying dates and you can change how the application displays dates using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

or, for your desired format:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI';
```

and then run your query. For other client applications, you will need to consult their documentation and update the preferences/settings in the application to your desired format.

---

If you want the value as a formatted string (and not a `DATE` data type) then use `TO_CHAR` on the date value:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE('3005231429', 'DDMMYYYYHH24MI'),
         'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` here with capture groups:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('300520231644',
                      '([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})',
                      '\1/\2/\3 \4:\5')
FROM dual;

-- 30/05/2023 16:44
```

### Demo